# Is it possible to modify a camera by changing cmos sensor?

Tags: cmos-image-sensor

I am currently looking at using a Basler Ace series camera (part no. acA3800-14um) which comes with the Aptina MT9J003 CMOS sensor. My question is, how easy would it be to change this sensor for another CMOS one at a later date, if required? Would it be possible, and if so, what sort of adjustments would be necessary?

Please see links for the camera and sensor hardware here:

[Camera](http://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/area-scan-cameras/ace/aca3800-14um)

[Sensor](https://www.aptina.com/products/image_sensors/mt9j003i12stcv/)

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the equipment to solder the new sensor and write new firmware for the camera to "talk" to that new sensor then yes it's possible.

Comment: ...plus the skills to reverse-engineer the hardware between the sensor and the firmware and make whatever changes will be needed to accommodate the new sensor.

Answer (score 1):

With only this information, I don't think it's possible. The new sensor would obviously need to be the same size to physically fit, which may or may not be a problem. Other aspects to how the sensor work are likely bigger limiters: this sensor outputs at 15 fps; a new sensor that outputs at, say, 30 fps would now require a processor capable of handling that larger amount of data, too, and that likely also means needing additional RAM to hold more images from a burst. Additionally, this sensor is 10 megapixels; let's say the new one is 20 MP, which will also require a processor, RAM, and bandwidth to handle the larger data quantity. So, to do something like this you would need to update far more than just the sensor and firmware.